# SSRS VS 2013 - Grouping and page breaks multiple different datasets

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services

I am looking to have a report repeat its data across multiple pages, group by / page break dependent on the project ID. This is simple enough with 1 tablix.

My issue is that I have 3 tablixes, each with their own data source due to different table structures. I am unable to union / join all 3 sets of data into 1 table. All 3 data sources can be linked by an project ID that is shared across all of the data for that project ID. What I am looking to do is repeat this report structure across multiple pages as defined by the project ID.

```
[Report Header]

[Tablix 1]
[Tablix 2]
[Tablix 3]

[Report Footer]
```

My current implementation uses a Rectangle that encases the 3 tablixes as they make up the "Report Data", however, there is no context to pass any sort of grouping parameter to children of the Rectangle.

Another thread recommends the potential use of sub-reports ([How to apply parent group for multiple datasets in SSRS VS2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598711/how-to-apply-parent-group-for-multiple-datasets-in-ssrs-vs2008)). I would like to avoid this design if possible due to the pitfalls it presents.

Comment: I have not found a way to do this easier than union-ing the datasets into one. And I have been looking for a better solution for this while using SSRS for 12 years. :) I am going to be doing that, again, on a new report tomorrow. Yeah!